# AWS S3: Setting a bucket policy for multiple users in an account

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-iam

I have an S3 bucket. And I have several IAM users in this account. I would like to set a **bucket policy** that multiple users can access this bucket.

For access to a single user, my bucket policy looks like so:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::8474632:user/personA"
            },
            "Action": [
                "s3:getObject",
                "s3:PutObject",
                "s3:DeleteObject",
                "s3:getObjectAcl",
                "s3:GetObjectVersion"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::thisbucket/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

I tried to change this line:

`"AWS": "arn:aws:iam::8474632:user/personA"`

to

`"AWS": "arn:aws:iam::8474632:user/*"`

to allow access to all users, but that doesn't work.

I could list all/some users one by one:

```
  "Principal": {
    "AWS": ["arn:aws:iam::111122223333:user/PersonA",
            "arn:aws:iam::111122223333:user/PersonB"]
  },
```

Is there a better way to allow access of a bucket to a group of users or all users?

Comment: Is there a reason you need a **bucket policy** and not an IAM policy attached to a group that the IAM users are members of?  An IAM policy would make it trivial to do

Comment: I've wondered about this. Should I place restrictions on users or on buckets? My thinking was to not place any restrictions on users, but rather finely control access to the buckets.

Comment: It really depends on your organization and your requirements. Best practices are to use IAM policies that define permissions to specific buckets, then assign those policies to groups and roles, then assign users to groups or allow users to assume the specific roles. You _can_ restrict at a bucket policy level (see [aws blog post](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/how-to-restrict-amazon-s3-bucket-access-to-a-specific-iam-role/)), but that becomes more difficult to maintain

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Probably an alternative way of doing this would be to use an IAM policy that is attached to all users. You would create a policy like:

```
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": [
            "s3:GetObject",
            "s3:GetObjectAcl",
            "s3:GetObjectVersion",
            "s3:GetObjectVersionAcl",
            "s3:GetObjectVersionTagging",
            "s3:PutObject",
            "s3:PutObjectAcl",
            "s3:PutObjectVersionAcl"
        ],
        "Resource": [
            "arn:aws:s3:::bucket_name/*"
        ]
    }
]
```

}

Then add that policy to a new role, and then associate that role with the users you want access.